# unable to parse unicode data(marathi font) from sql xml

Tags: sql, xml, parsing, select

I am trying to parse sql xml to get marathi data fonts from it, but i am getting ???????. i have tried NVARCHAR in xml but still facing error, any suggestion please? please click sql query link to see my code.

[sql query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pv7br.png)
for address i am getting ??????????

I have tried a lot but not getting marathi data

Answer (score 0):

Force your string value to `unicode`, add `'N'` on the beginning.

```
declare @ResearcherAddress xml =  N'<?xml version="1.0"?><ArrayOfResearcherAddress xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><ResearcherAddress><AddressTypeId>1</AddressTypeId><Address>N''संबंधीत संस्थेचे आर्थिक व्यवहार राष्ट्रीयकृत/ शेड्युल बँकेमार्फत केले जात असल्याचे कागदपत्रसंबंधीत संस्थेचे आर्थिक व्यवहार राष्ट्रीयकृत/ शेड्युल बँकेमार्फत केले जात असल्याचे कागदपत्र''</Address><DistrictCode>520</DistrictCode><SubDistrictCode>4173</SubDistrictCode><StateCode>27</StateCode><CityVillageName>pethali</CityVillageName><PinCode>410208</PinCode></ResearcherAddress><ResearcherAddress><AddressTypeId>2</AddressTypeId><Address>andheri, mumbai</Address><DistrictCode>711</DistrictCode><SubDistrictCode>5929</SubDistrictCode><StateCode>27</StateCode><CityVillageName>chakala jb</CityVillageName><PinCode>400093</PinCode></ResearcherAddress></ArrayOfResearcherAddress>'

select ResProfAddress.value('(Address/text())[1]','NVARCHAR(150)')
FROM @ResearcherAddress.nodes(N'/ArrayOfResearcherAddress/ResearcherAddress')AS TEMPTABLE(ResProfAddress)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, :) its working now.  you saved my time of redeveloping a code,